# Why do is it called estimation of depth, trajectory etc. and not measure?

Tags: computer-vision, measurement

With the help of computer vision we can estimate the velocity of an object or estimate the depth of a scene etc.

But why is it not called measurement? Is not every measurement, even outside of computer vision, an estimation? In other areas, however, it is not called estimation, but measurement or calculation.

Can someone explain this please?

Comment: In everyday language, these are synonyms. Why do you worry ?

Comment: I think the terminology illustrates more the uncertainty of these authors in their own methods, than the uncertainty of the measurements themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An image already is the result of a measurement, which may or may not reflect the original quantities present in the underlying data. You could for example have some sort of noise in your image which was generated during the acquisition process.

I'd say that can't really reliably *measure* real world quantities like depth of a scene or velocity of an object from images, since images can always introduce different sorts of noise or artefacts which make it impossible to restore these original quantities based on the image data alone. You can however *estimate* these quantities based on the data you have, given that estimation is per definition more of an educated guess based on what you can observe.

**In short:** Images are not necessarily accurate depictions of reality, even in the best case scenario they will only reflect part of the underlying truth (alone due to the fact that they are discretised). Estimation does per definition already include some form of uncertainty and that's probably why most literature uses this term instead.

Comment: “Estimation does per definition already include some form of uncertainty” So does measurement.

Comment: @CrisLuengo  Sure, I did not state it otherwise. Of course there are also errors in all kinds measurements, but then again there is no way to get completely *certain* data. Don't you agree that the word estimation implies uncertainty rather than measuring?

Comment: I do agree that "estimation" implies more uncertainty than "measure", in common parlance. But in science these words have different meaning than in common parlance: one measures a quantity, one estimates the parameters of a model. A measurement can be very imprecise or inaccurate, an estimate can be very precise and accurate.

Comment: Also, I don't agree that you can't measure through an image. Just because there could be noise in the image doesn't turn the measurement into a guess.

Comment: no idea why anyone would vote your answer down. it's spot on for such a broad question. if the question was more specific, I would have given concrete examples (e.g. issues in calculating disparity maps) but that's it.